# Use Google Maps Indoor Map API in HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to create a indoor map application using HTML5 and JavaScript. I have created a simple road map application, but when I click to zoom in on any indoor compatible building/mall, there are no levels or flooring options. So, are indoor features supported with HTML5 and Javascript?

In any normal Google Map in a mobile application, when we zoom in to any indoor building so it's enabled and show the floor wise map on screen.

Comment: I know that[indoor maps are only currently supported in some locations](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1685872). Are you unable to see indoor maps in your app that *do* show up on maps.google.com?

Comment: According to the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504903/indoor-map-with-google-maps), indoor maps aren’t supported in the API — although the reference link from the answer is now dead.

Comment: Oh dear, that answer has now been deleted.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing: Is JavaScript v3 API supporting indoors maps or not ?  I couldn't find anything from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the JavaScript v3 API does not yet support indoor maps. But it might come.

The official page says it **will** be available: https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

> "In addition to making the content available to our users in Google
>   Maps, your indoor map **will also be available** through the Google Maps
>   APIs for use in your mobile applications or **website**."

Comment: Wow, I was searching for the same identical question, but it seems that after two years Google never pushed a dedicated API for it.