# Find out if a location/place has a floor plan in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Based on a address/location/place I would like to check if this place has a floor plan or not in google maps. Unfortunately in couldnt find anything in the Google Place API or any other API from google maps.

Only when this place has a floor plan, google maps is shown .
Any ideas how I check if floor plan for a place? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987890/use-google-maps-indoor-map-api-in-html5-and-javascript

Answer (score 5):

The Indoor Maps are  available in [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps) and [iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_indoor_display) , but not int he Google Maps API JS.
Please star [this issue tracker FR](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4351) to get notified when this gets implemented

There is no way to programatically check if a given location is "indoor enabled".
The closest you can to such a check is the [getFocusedBuilding](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getFocusedBuilding()) function which will get the current focused building or null if no building is focused (implying there is no indoor map)

Answer (score -2):

## Indoor maps

> At high zoom levels, the map shows floor plans for indoor spaces such as airports, shopping malls, large retail stores, and transit stations. These floor plans, called indoor maps, are displayed for the 'normal' and 'satellite' map types (**`GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`** and **`GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE`**). They are automatically enabled when the user zooms in, and they fade away when the map is zoomed out.

Indoor maps (floor plans) are available in [select locations](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827). If floor plan data is not available for a building that you would like to highlight in your application, you can:

- [Add floor plans](https://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/) to Google Maps directly. This will make your floor plans available to all users of Google Maps.
- Display a floor plan as a [ground overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) or [tile overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) on your map. This will enable only users of your application to view your floor plans.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply! But for which API is that? I am using the Googe Maps Javascript API and i tried to call map.isIndoorEnabled() but that doesnt work.

Comment: Mr Rebot is referring to Android SDK. JS API does not yet have support for Indoor Maps - you can star this FR to get updated when it's implemented: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4351

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from the Google Maps Native SDK documentation and does not answer the question. Flagged for closing.